# Aspect creation in Dspace

Tags: dspace

I am new to DSpace. I just wanted to create  my own DSPACE Customized aspect in Dspace6.0

Can anyone help with the steps required to create these Customized aspects in DSpace 6.0

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps you need to take to create a new aspect in DSpace:

- Write a sitemap to list the aspect's pipelines and the components that those pipelines use.
- Write a transformer java class (a subclass of AbstractDSpaceTransformer) and add it to the new sitemap
- Add the new aspect to dspace/config/xmlui.xconf to enable it

More information and examples can be found on the [DSpace wiki](https://wiki.duraspace.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=19006128)